# LTSpice produces incorrect simulation for Class AB amplifier

Tags: simulation, ltspice, gain, class-ab

I have been building a Class AB amplifier simulation using LTSpice.
While it simulates well for transient analysis (voltage gain of 0.9 at peak), 
using ac analysis the the voltage gain drops to 0.268.

I also tried using zener diodes, and these do work well for ac analysis, however they are not common place in Class AB amps.

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Circuit

[image]

Transient Analysis
[image]

AC Analysis
[image]

Comment: Thats not a class AB amplifier... https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/amplifier-amp110.gif

Comment: Oh yes it is @BeB00 [better picture](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Olaf_Graven/publication/275939075/figure/fig3/AS:668916586143747@1536493550532/Basic-circuit-of-class-AB-power-amplifier-with-single-power-supply.png)

Comment: @MarioParnis The vertical scale in your AC analysis - is it volts/volt or in decibels? Also, in your signal generator, what is the signal amplitude set to for specifically AC analysis (not transient analysis). I use microcap and you can set them independently but I'm not sure about LTspice.

Comment: @Mario P....The ac analysis is always a small-signal LINEAR analysis. Hence, yu must not expect meaningful results if the circuit is non-linear (as in your case).

Comment: You are modeling the crossover distortion-  linearized about the DC operating point. See @Mario's comment.

Comment: If you reduce the bias resistors you'll see the crossover distortion reduce and the AC analysis approach the large-signal behavior.

Comment: I think basically the lesson here is that the 1 volt magnitude is ignored other than scaling the output. Nonlinear elements are linearized exactly about the operating point.

Comment: Because it is biased directly in the middle of the crossover distortion. https://i.imgur.com/a7AKcg4.png

Comment: It's your circuit with input vs. output at 1kHz- I just zoomed in on the zero crossing. Pink is input and Green is output, and as you can see the slope near 0V is much lower than the slope (gain) a couple hundred mV on either side of 0V.

Comment: The 2V magnitude you set in AC analysis is ignored in doing the analysis, it's linearized mathematically right at the DC operating point and then scaled as if it was linear to whatever magnitude.

Comment: And basically AC analysis is not too useful here.

Comment: More than that...it gives wrong results...

Comment: @MarioParnis Don't forget that you have a NPN and a PNP, which means one will need different biasing than the other. What you have there is very symmetric. All in all, I'd rather not blame the tool first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

With base bias resistors of 10K, two series diodes have too-little current flowing through them. At LTSpice's 27 degree C default, only 0.5569114 volt drops across each diode. That's not enough to bias the complementary pair of transistors with much "class AB" DC bias current - only 23.66 uA DC is pulled from the 12V supply through Q1,Q2. This is more Class-B than Class-AB.

AC analysis proceeds:
Transistor characteristics are first found with 23.66 uA DC current flowing. All the transistor parameters are **linearized** at this bias point.  Base bias diodes are linearized similarly.
**This is where simulation problems can arise...diodes become resistors, transistors can have unreasonably large (or small) current gain** because these parameters are extrapolated linearly to extremes.

Transient analysis gives a more-true simulation, but requires much more involved and time-consuming calculations. A **transient analysis**, done with tiny input amplitude approaches similarity to **AC analysis**. Its results converge with the (bogus) AC analysis (left):
[image: low-amplitude transient analysis LTspice]

 When the transient analysis is done with higher amplitude (plot at right), you can see the cross-over "glitch" where the small-amplitude (plot at left) is done.
These two transient runs appear to disagree, yet each is a reasonable result, scanning different sections of a non-linear transfer-function.